# Can anyone ID this bathroom fan motor?

Tags: bathroom, fans

I need to replace this fan motor, I believe it's Broan, but could also be NuTone. I have tried looking up the number stamped on the side, but nothing comes up for either of those manufacturers. Does anyone recognize this or have any luck finding an actual replacement?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Bathroom fan motor][image: Bathroom fan and housing]

Comment: Any labels or stickers on the parts you removed?

Comment: Those are really easy to replace. Unplug it, and pop out the motor-fan-faceplate assembly (there are some metal tabs).  A new unit can be purchased for $15 (in the USA). The motor-fan-faceplate should be compatible. You can just pop it in and plug it back in.

Comment: Can you show pic of  finish cover ?  And some even have it on cover.  It does look like Broan so far.

Comment: These motors are pretty standard.  The basic Broan motor will most likely work regardless of what exact brand and model this is.

Comment: @RobertMoody I looked on the cover and didn't see anything.

Comment: I haven't removed any parts yet. I planned on doing that once I got the replacement part. Thank you Stephen and JPhi. I had the same thought that most any motor would work. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yes one of us may know by looking at it.

Comment: You can get a upgrade kit for fans. If fan did not have enough. SCFM and  move more air.

Comment: I have done this enough. Where i can tell you by cover. What brand you have. or you can have the pros.. And i am done.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part there are only a few manufacturers of those fan motors, regardless of what brand the fan is. Most of them are interchangeable, but the critical dimension that you often must deal with is the length of the shaft that the fan itself is attached to (and how it attaches). You will need to remove it to determine what you need.

What I have found on the last 3 of these is that the replacement motor costs as much as the entire fan, but the entire fan unit was not going to match the sheet metal work, so swapping it out was more than I wanted to do. So I cleaned the motors and fans really well, put them back in and they worked fine. So far, 3 more years of life on the oldest one. It's worth a try.

Comment: Unless the windings are damaged, cleaning an lubrication should work.

Comment: Have you found any particular brand/types of cleaners and lubricants works better than others?

Comment: You want specific electrical cleaners, they are tested not to damage insulation materials. CRC is a common brand name I use, there are others. Just make sure it says it is electrical cleaner or contact cleaner (as in electrical contacts). Some of them state that they can be used on energized equipment, but DO NOT dot that.